# Check DOM element in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple Google Chrome extension - like finding a specific element on the page and display an alert.

My problem is that the specific page loads relatively slow (having also some AJAX behind).

How can I make my check only when all the page is loaded?

I tried `"run_at" : "document_idle"` in my manifest file, but with no success. It shows me the message, before the whole page loads.

I was thinking to check every second (or something) the whole DOM elements, but is this a feasible solution? I think it will slow down the page...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that element does not exist on the page when you click "view source", then one way of catching it would be listening to `DOMSubtreeModified` event, which fires each time DOM is modified:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
        if(document.getElementById("my_element")) {
                //element is added
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. My page loads a lot of elements using AJAX. So this is really slowing down my page. For each element added, the script runs. Can I restrict this to, let's say, only when adding an element (div, text field, ...)?

Comment: @Parkyprg There is also `DOMNodeInserted` event. But I don't understand why this slows down the page. You shouldn't run any script inside this event handler, just check if element is already on the page or not. If it is - then you run your script once (have some flag or something).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put your code in window.onload event in "content_script.js"?

```
window.onload = function() {
   // your code
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This fires when the window loads, but before all the elements are updated with AJAX.